# How to rename a batch of files in a directory?

Tags: php

I have a bunch of files in a directory that I would like to rename. I have a complete list of existing file names and in the column next to the old name, I have a new name (desired) filename, like below: (the list is in excel so I can apply some syntax to all the rows very easily)

```
OLD NAME         NEW NAME
--------         --------
aslkdjal.pdf     asdlkjkl.pdf
adkjlkjk.pdf     asdlkjdj.pdf
```

I would like to keep the old name and old files in their current directory and not disturb them, but just create a copy of the file, with the new filename instead.

Not sure what language to use and how to go about doing this.

Comment: Your looking at using PHP or another server-side language. Definitely not JS or SQL

Comment: make it a batch file containing `copy oldname newname` for each file.

Comment: server is LAMP i am using windows on my laptop

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Just try with the following example :***

```
<?php
$source = '../_documents/fees';
$target = '../_documents/aifs';

$newnames= array(
    "1276.aif.pdf" => "aif.10001.pdf",
    "64.aif.20091127.pdf" => "aif.10002.pdf",
);

function recurse_copy($src,$dst) {
    $dir = opendir($src);
    @mkdir($dst);
    while(false !== ( $file = readdir($dir)) ) {

        if (( $file != '.' ) && ( $file != '..' )) {
            if ( is_dir($src . '/' . $file) ) {
                recurse_copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
            else {
                copy($src . '/' . $file,$dst . '/' . $file);
            }
        }
    }
    closedir($dir);
}

// Copy all files to a new dir
recurse_copy($source, $target);

// Iterate through this dir, rename all files.
$i = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($target);

foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($i) as $filename => $file) {    
    @rename($filename, $target.'/'.$newnames[''.$i.'']);    
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php

```
<?php
rename("/tmp/tmp_file.txt", "/home/user/login/docs/my_file.txt");
?>
```

EDIT: in case of [copy](http://php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) -

```
<?php
$file = 'example.txt';
$newfile = 'example.txt.bak';

if (!copy($file, $newfile)) {
    echo "failed to copy $file...\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: he wants to keep the original file. 'copy' file instead of 'rename'.

Comment: @BenJones: Nope, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
$source = '/files/folder';
$target = '/files/newFolder';
$newnames= array(
    "oldfilename" => "newfilename",
    "oldfilename1" => "newfilename1",
);

// Copy all files to a new dir
if (!copy($source, $target)) {
    echo "failed to copy $source...\n";
}

// Iterate through this dir, rename all files.
$i = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($target);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($i) as $filename => $file) {
    rename($filename, $newnames[$filename]);
    // You might need to use $file as first parameter, here. Haven't tested the code.
}
```

[RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) documentation.

Comment: @cerbus is this better than the answer above?

Comment: In my opinion, it is, obviously.
It's more complete, at least. (The other answer simply copied 2 pieces of code from the php documentation)

Comment: am I correct to say that this method will rename all the files whereas the answer above will only rename one at a time?

Comment: That is correct. Assuming you have a `$newnames` array that has all the conversions listed, this will be a fully automatic solution.

Comment: I have a list in excel, of over 1,000 old names and new names, side by side, and that is where I will put the names, in the array... gotcha. Now isn't this missing something like i++ ?

Comment: @BenJones: Nope, the `foreach` will iterate through each directory / file it finds in the copied directory.

Comment: and I'm a little confused as to how I would implement this code? save this in a PHP file on the server and then go to that page?? Thanks

Comment: You might want to take a look at some [php tutorials](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.php). (Basically, yes, save it to a `.php` on your server and open it in the browser.)

Comment: Thanks @cebrus you've helped out a bunch!

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty easy to do with a shell script. Start with the file list as you presented in `files.txt`.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Set the 'line' delimiter to a newline
IFS="
"

# Go through each line of files.txt and use it to call the copy command
for line in `cat files.txt`; do 
  cp `echo $line | awk '{print $1;}'` `echo $line | awk '{print $2};'`; 
done
```